# CHART.JS scriptable backgroupColor attribute

Tags: chart.js, background-color

I'm trying to change the background color of a bar chart made with chart.js based on the value.

I found a lot of examples, but I read on chart.js documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html?h=backgroundcolor) that the background color is scriptable.

I cannot find where and how to configure options in order to achieve this result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61028048/2358409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution proposed by @uminder can be one solution, but this requires that all data mist be preprocessed and an array of colors filled before the creation of the graph.

With this solution https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/55dd7ded0e7c6133c615c28aa3d46ab97ea08a82/test/fixtures/controller.bar/backgroundColor/scriptable.js#L10 no preprocessing is needed and the color is selected "on-the-fly".

I was looking for this type of solution I've just found in the test suite of chartjs.