# I want to put bar of different color by the values in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am creating different chat for analysis one of them is bar chart in which i need to fill color according to the value if value is less than or equal to 20 color is red,if 20 to 60 color should be yellow and if it is more than 60 than it should be green.

code is below given

JS:-

```
var ctx6 = document.querySelector('#resultsChart6').getContext('2d');
var options6 = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
      labels: ['Label1','Label2','Label3','Label4','Label5'],
      responsive: false,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Your Score in %",
        data: [((section1Total / (section1Question * 5)) * 100),((section2Total / (section2Question * 5)) * 100),((section3Total / (section3Question * 5)) * 100),((section4Total / (section4Question * 5)) * 100),((section5Total / (section5Question * 5)) * 100)],
        backgroundColor: '#2ecc71'
      }
          
      ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
       position: 'top' // place legend on the right side of chart
    },
    scales: {
       xAxes: [{
          stacked: true // this should be set to make the bars stacked
       }],
       yAxes: [{
          stacked: true // this also..
       }]
    }
 }
}

new Chart(ctx6, options6);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61028048/2358409

Comment: @uminder i need to have different condition to fill three color not two ... so that will not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scriptable options for this:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 20, 23, 50, 60, 65],
      backgroundColor: (ctx) => {
        if (ctx.raw <= 20) {
          return 'red';
        }

        if (ctx.raw <= 60) {
          return 'yellow';
        }

        return 'green';
      }
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```